# Member function static variable vs member variable

Tags: c++, static

Is it a good practice to use a static variable inside member function instead of member variable for a variable that should preserve its value between function calls?

Consider the following example: I have a class with an `update()` function where some 3D object is being rotated every frame. I sometimes see the following code:

```
void Class::update(float frameTime)
{
    static float rotation = 0.0f;
    rotation + = m_rotationSpeed * frameTime
    if (rotation >= 360.0f) rotation -= 360.0f;
    // ...
}
```

This can just as well be implemented using a member variable.

Are there any reasons to prefer one implementation over the other? It seems to me like using a static like this does improve encapsulation and also results in a smaller object, but on the other hand it seems somewhat less intuitive.

Please note that a class like that is usually meant to be used in single instance, and, since C++11, static variable should be thread safe.

Comment: Have you ever considered that you maybe want to change your rotation something, e.g resetting it? Usually rotation is a common property of any render object and should be exposed.

Comment: So if and only if there is a single instance, what is the difference in size requirements if that variable is not static!???

Comment: I've seen something like this in more than one place which is the reason for this question. I'm not advocating this approach, just trying to find out why someone might have coded it like this.    

@Paranaix this method is not a member of the object being rotated, but some class representing a scene or even the main game loop, so the rotation would then be passed to the object e.g. `object.setRotationY(rotation)`, but I see your point.

Answer (score 4):

It makes very little sense to use a `static` variable here, because *all* instances of `Class` will access the same variable. It is very unlikely that you need to share `rotation` between instances like this.

If you want to restrict a class to being a single instance, then you have to make sure it can only be instantiated once. But this is usually a sign that a re-design is in order.

Comment: Does it mean that majority of modern game engines and rendering engines need re-design?

Answer (score 0):

I would say if you use singleton approach it's meaningless using static field. Even if your project won't get any bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* go with static typically. Static means you can use it without declaring an object. Static doesn't fit your case. Just because there's only one of it doesn't mean it needs to be static.

Static is useful usually when you have something perhaps you want to be able to compare to without two instances of the object.

I.e perhaps you have a shape object, and it has an enum for color. By making the enum static, you can do something such as `if(myShape.shapeColor == Shape::color::red)` Usually however, I stay away from static. It's one of those things that has its uses and doesn't need to be broadened any further.

Edit:

Actually, making the enum static in that case won't change anything. I guess I'll to try to keep my answer somewhat valid, and so I'll pretend that you could not use enums in this case. (Even though this is a c++ question, I'm just getting a point across). You could declare say, a series of constant static integers. You would not be forced to have two objects for comparisons.

Comment: Declaring the enum static in this case doesn't actually change anything.

Comment: @Marian Oh wow, you're right, haha. I'll make an edit, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Using static like this is ok for a small application however as the application grows larger there then becomes the issue of using static where you would want to use a member variable due to the scalability of it over using static.

Answer (score -1):

There is no 'good pratice' here as they don't do the same thing :

- A member variable (attribute) will be updated only by the current instance of the class.
- A static variable will be modified by all the instances of that class.

For example the class

```
class Foo
{
 void bar() 
 {
  static int bar = 0;

  std::cout << bar << std::endl;
  bar++;
 }
};
```

given this main

```
int main() 
{
 Foo one, two;

 one.bar();
 two.bar();
 two.bar();
 one.bar();
}
```

will output

```
1
2
3
4
```